# What is the endomorphism cooperad?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, qa.quantum-algebra, operads, koszul-duality

In Loday and Vallette's book on algebraic operads, they use the "Endomorphism cooperad $End^c_{s\mathbb{K}}$", where $s\mathbb{K}$ is the base field, shifted into (homological) degree one. This is an important ingredient in the defining equation of the Koszul dual operad of a Koszul operad. Namely, given a Koszul operad $\mathcal{O}$ we have (in their notation)

$\mathcal{O}^!= (\mathcal{S}^c \otimes_H \mathcal{O}^{antishrik})^*$

where $\mathcal{O}^{antishrik}$ is the Koszul dual cooperad of $\mathcal{O}$,
$\otimes_H$ is the (cooperad) Hadamard tensor and $\mathcal{S}^c$ is this  cooperad $End^c_{s\mathbb{K}}$. In their book this is 7.2.2. and 7.2.3

Now the question: Can someone explain what the endomorphism cooperad $End^c_V$, for a given graded vector space (or more general: Chain complex), is? If I'm not mistaken, they don't define it in their book and I couldn't find a definition elsewhere, either.

Is it the linear dual of the coendomorphism operad of $V$ (at least if $V$ is finite dimensional)? In that case, I think one has to be very careful regarding the signs! It is not as easy as with the endomorphism operad.

I mean the cocomposition then involves signs, which are not there in the endomorphism operad and which come from the signs involved in the linear dual of graded vector spaces. I think this has not been made explicit anywhere, so far.

Comment: My guess is it would be the dual of the endomorphism operad? I don't think there's a problem with signs using the Koszul rule.